# Custom EditText with rectangle drawn around it not compatible with gravity

Tags: android, android-edittext, gravity

I am trying to create a custom EditText class with a rectangle drawn around it. I got that to work rather easily. But then I also wanted the text to be centered and therefore I set gravity = center. However that made the rectangle around the box disappear. Is the gravity property changing the bounding box? How can I retrieve the correct bounding box?

The class is as follows:

```
public static class LetterBox extends EditText {

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public LetterBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setupPaint();
    }

    public LetterBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        this.setupPaint();
        super.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }

    public LetterBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
        this.setupPaint();
        super.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,getMeasuredWidth()-1,getMeasuredHeight()-1,mPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void setupPaint() {
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)?

Comment: Thanks. Did not help tough.

Comment: How are you building the Letterbox object? With findViewById?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your code and it is working as expected. The only thing I had to change was remove the `static` modifier from the class. Did you intend to use `static`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. I declared it as static because I hade it as a sub-class to my main activity. However, if I moved it to its own source file and remove static I still cannot get it to work. What API version did you use?

Comment: targetSDKVersion="19", running on an emulator with API level 16. I also have the support libraries v4 and v7 in use.